# Unnable to add RESTEasy WS

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jboss, resteasy

According to [this](http://docs.jboss.org/seam/2.2.2.Final/reference/en-US/html/webservices.html#d0e22185) manual it should be piece of cake to add a web service, but I'm struggling to make it accessible.
Here is the code:

```
@Name("examineeController")
@Path("/examinee")
public class ExamineeController {

    @GET
    @Produces("text/plain")
    @Path("/setteststatus")
    private String updateProjectTestStatus(/) {
        return "OK";
    }
```

...and receive 404 like that:

`HTTP Status 404 - Could not find resource for relative : /examinee/setteststatus of full path: http://localhost:8080/am/seam/resource/rest/examinee/setteststatus`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most epic of my epic fails. `private String updateProjectTestStatus(/)` `private`!!! It has to be `public`!